# draw a texture pixelated

Tags: graphics, webgl

I have a bitmap that I want to draw zoomed in and with straight, defined edges between pixels.

I have tried setting the MAG filter to NEAREST:

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,this.tex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
...
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0,6); // draw the texture
```

However, when I draw it the pixels bleed together:

[image]

This is webGL so I have shaders.  My shader code is super-simple:

Vertex shader:

```
...
attribute vec2 texCoord;
varying vec2 texel;
void main() {
    texel = texCoord;
    ...
```

And fragment shader:

```
...
varying vec2 texel;
uniform sampler2D texture;
void main() {
    vec4 fragColour = texture2D(texture,texel);
    ...
```

Here's a larger snippet of the relative code:

```
map = {
    vbo: gl.createBuffer(),
    tex: gl.createTexture(),
    program: createProgram(
        "precision mediump float;\n"+
        "uniform mat4 mvMatrix, pMatrix;\n"+
        "attribute vec3 vertex;\n"+
        "attribute vec2 texCoord;\n"+
        "varying vec2 texel;\n"+
        "void main() {\n"+
        "   texel = texCoord;\n"+
        "   gl_Position = pMatrix * mvMatrix * vec4(vertex,1.0);\n"+
        "}\n",
        "precision mediump float;\n"+
        "uniform vec4 colour;\n"+
        "uniform float fogDensity;\n"+
        "uniform vec4 fogColour;\n"+
        "varying vec2 texel;\n"+
        "uniform sampler2D texture;\n"+
        "const float LOG2 = 1.442695;\n"+
        "void main() {\n"+
        "   float z = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;\n"+
        "   float fogFactor = exp2(-fogDensity*fogDensity*z*z*LOG2);\n"+
        "   fogFactor = clamp(fogFactor,0.0,1.0);\n"+
        "   vec4 fragColour = texture2D(texture,texel) * colour;\n"+
        "   gl_FragColor = mix(fogColour,fragColour,fogFactor);\n"+
        "}\n",
        ["mvMatrix","pMatrix","colour","fogDensity","fogColour","texture"],
        ["vertex","texCoord"]),
    plane: [[0,0,0],[0,1,0]],
    init: function(w,h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        var vertices = [
            w,0,0,  1,0,
            0,0,0,  0,0,
            w,0,h,  1,1,
            w,0,h,  1,1,
            0,0,0,  0,0,
            0,0,h,  0,1,
        ];
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.vbo);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(vertices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,null);
        this._mapArrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(w*h*4);
        this._mapByteBuffer = new Uint8Array(this._mapArrayBuffer);
        this.map = new Uint32Array(this._mapArrayBuffer);
        for(var i=0; i<w*h; i++) // test data: red and green pixels
            this.map[i] = Math.random()>0.5? 0xff000080: 0xff008000;
        createTexture(this.tex,w,h,this._mapByteBuffer,true);
    },
    draw: function() {
        var program = this.program;
        gl.useProgram(program);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.pMatrix,false,camera.pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.mvMatrix,false,camera.mvMatrix);
        gl.uniform4f(program.colour,1,1,1,1);
        gl.uniform4f(program.fogColour,1,1,1,1);
        gl.uniform1f(program.fogDensity,0.03);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,this.tex);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.vbo);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertex);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertex,3,gl.FLOAT,false,5*4,0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.texCoord);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.texCoord,2,gl.FLOAT,false,5*4,3*4);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0,6);
        gl.disableVertexAttribArray(program.texCoord);
        gl.disableVertexAttribArray(program.vertex);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,null);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
        gl.useProgram(null);
    },
};

function createTexture(tex,width,height,data,noMipMap) {
    tex = tex || gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,tex);
    tex.width = width || data.width;
    tex.height = height || data.height;
    if(width != null)
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,width,height,0,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,data || null);
    else
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
    if(anisotropy)
        gl.texParameterf(gl.TEXTURE_2D,anisotropic.TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT,anisotropy);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.LINEAR);
    if(!noMipMap && !(tex.width&(tex.width-1)) && !(tex.height&(tex.height-1))) { //pow2
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    } else
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.LINEAR);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
    _textures.push(tex);
    return tex;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should be using glBindSampler() instead of glBindTexture() - http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)

Comment: @roger_rowland: [Sampler *objects*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object) (you linked to the wrong page) don't exist in WebGL.

Comment: @Will: Can you post more of your code? It's not clear that you're using the texture you set those parameters onto. Also, have you tried checking for OpenGL errors? Oh, and what does the actual texture look like?

Comment: With webgl one possibility of failure is that there's an extra stage of interpolation from canvas to screen. (OTOH the default canvas size on most browsers is 400x300) What's the size of your framebuffer?

Comment: @NicolBolas I've pasted a bit more context.  The problem is self-contained here I think.  The texture is just a 100x100 random green and red pixels.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen my canvas size is the size of the window and other things I draw are drawn correctly.  It just as though in this particular texture's case the TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER is not sticking :(

Comment: Please do not edit the question to add the answer. Instead add the answer as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[SOLVED]*** The problem was that I was enabling anisotropy for the texture.  Anisotropy trumps gl_NEAREST, it seems.  If you want to use gl_NEAREST on a texture, its important to not also have anisotropy set.